# How to read data from log analytics Custom table

Tags: logging, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm trying to send data across log analytics workspaces using logic app for this purpose i have used send data action that creates a custom log table.

The problem that when i wanted to use this table in KQL query i cannot access to some rows
example :
when i want to get Setting name from data_s row i get this error
[image]

Row Definition

[image]

Does anyone know how to access these rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `Data_s` is of type `string` but is a valid JSON payload, you'll need to first use `parse_json()` on it to be able to access properties in it.

for example:

```
datatable(Data_s: string) ['{"SettingName":"PurgeRuns"}']
| extend Data_d = parse_json(Data_s)
| where Data_d.SettingName in ("PurgeRuns","PurgeArtifacts")
```